# python curses not recognizing arrow keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, curses

i have this simple program . there is no error in the program also the when i press q the program exits

```
import curses

def main(stdscr):
    while 1:
        Key = stdscr.getch()
        if Key == curses.KEY_UP:
            stdscr.addstr(0,0,'u pressed up key ')
            stdscr.refresh()
        elif Key == curses.KEY_DOWN:
            stdscr.addstr(0,0,'u pressed down key')
            stdscr.refresh()
        elif Key == curses.KEY_LEFT:
            stdscr.addstr(0,0,'u pressed left key')
            stdscr.refresh()
        elif Key == curses.KEY_RIGHT:
            stdscr.addstr(0,0,'u pressed right key')
            stdscr.refresh()
        elif Key == ord('q'):
            break
curses.wrapper(main)
```

Comment: It works fine on my Macbook Air running Python 3.8. I can see the "u pressed .. key" when I press any of the arrow keys". Can you post your OS and Python version details.

Comment: i am using lubuntu and python version 3.8.6

Comment: it is probably the terminal emulator you are using which is not passing through the arrow key inputs to your python program.  download a different terminal emulator, such as kitty, lxterm, or konsole, and try it in that

Comment: yeah that was the problem i tried it with xterm  and its works thankss

Answer (score 1):

If `getkey` on arrow keys is giving you letters {A|B|C|D} and `getch` is giving your their numeric equivalents, call `.keypad(True)` on the window from which you're reading. [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.window.keypad)

```py
stdscr.keypad(True)
key = stdscr.getch()
stdscr.addstr(0, 0, '%s' % key == curses.KEY_UP)
```

This will have curses interpret the arrow keys' entire escape sequence for you.